# Run a function only once when a certain condition is met but rest of another condition is met

Tags: jquery

I am not sure how to achieve the above, ill try to explain better below.

i have an if else statement

```
resizeDiv = function() {    
if (vpw < 600) {
//do something 1
}
else
{
//do something 2
}
};
$(document).ready(resizeDiv);
$(window).bind('resize', resizeDiv);
```

As you can see from the above i have this bound to resize and load of my page, my problem is they trigger every time i resize the page (whis is correct from the above code.

what i need to happen is lets say VPW is < 600 it runs //do something 1 only once if i resize my browser again it wont run as its already been done.

then if i resize to >600 //do something 2 triggers and then if i resize back down to <600 //do something 1 will trigger again only once ill try to explain this below with code too.

```
resizeDiv = function() {    
if (vpw < 600) {
//do something 1
//disable do something 1
//enable do something 2
}
else
{
//do something 2
//disable do something 2
//enable do something 1
}
};
$(document).ready(resizeDiv);
$(window).bind('resize', resizeDiv);
```

Hopefully this all makes sense and someone might be able to point me in the right direction to achieve what i need to happen

Ragards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a simple state like

```
var state;
resizeDiv = function () {
    if (vpw < 600 && state != 1) {
        //do something 1
        state = 1;
        console.log('less', state)
    } else if (vpw >= 600 && state != 2) {
        //do something 2
        state = 2;
        console.log('more', state)
    }
};
$(document).ready(resizeDiv);
$(window).bind('resize', resizeDiv);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5c5j5zsg/)

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish what you want you would have to keep track of the current "state", and do something accordingly.

Let's say you have two states `state1` and `state2`, then you would only want to do `something2` when the state is currently `state1`, and vice versa. It's a bit similar to saving that you have "done" `something2`.

In code I would approach it like this:

```
var state = "nostate"; // you could also set this to the state it starts in.
resizeDiv = function() {   
    if (vpw < 600 && state != "state2") {
        //do something 1

        //enable do something 2
        state = "state2";
    } else if(vpw >= 600 && state != "state1") {
        //do something 2

        //enable do something 1
        state = "state1";
    } else {
        // do nothing.
    }
};
$(document).ready(resizeDiv);
$(window).bind('resize', resizeDiv);
```

Comment: thank you, same as below and missed yours first went with this solution and Arun P's

Answer (score 1):

I recommend `$(window).resize();` and `$(document).ready()` instead. But you must run the function inside both of them. `$(window).resize();` mean while you resize the browser, and `$(document).ready();` is when the page load.

Firstly, define your function for resize

```
function resizeDiv(){
  var vpw = $(window).width; // if vpw is based on whole page width
   if (vpw < 600) {
     alert('Less than 600px');
     //do something 1
   }
   else
   {
     alert('More than 600px');
     //do something 2
   }
}
```

Then do the function inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   resizeDiv();
   // you can explain other function when your page is READY
});

$(window).resize(function(){
   resizeDiv();
   // also here for other function when your page is on RESIZE
});
```

Note:

Make sure your page isn't defining `$(document).ready();` or `$(window).resize();`.

Because defining multiple `$(document).ready();` or `$(window).resize();` causing error.

Comment: thank you for your comment, i do have it wrapped in a doc ready.. sorry didn't not post that..

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery's `.one` function : http://api.jquery.com/one/ As its name suggests, it executes a function only once.

Otherwise, just use a boolean variable to keep record if something has already been done :

```
var doneOnce = false

doSomething(){
     /* stuff stuff stuff */
     doneOnce = true;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, above is the answer i chose, needed it to happen more then once

Comment: Well, you explicitely stated that you wanted it to happen only once, and now you chose a different answer because it allows to happen more than once. I'm getting confused.

Comment: it was hard to explain hence the 2nd bit of code which i hope helped, i value your comment